# Error in SQL Server trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I am writing a trigger for the first time. I want to check that if value =4 then Exon N, Date Fin,Date début must not be null

```
CREATE TRIGGER tgr_suspTVA
   ON dbo.F_COMPTET
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @N_CatCompta int, @ExonN varchar(69),
            @dateFin datetime, @dateDeb datetime 

    SELECT @N_CatCompta = N_CatCompta, 
           @ExonN = [Exon N°], 
           @dateFin = [Date Fin],
           @dateDeb = [Date début]

    IF (@N_CatCompta=4) AND (@ExonN IS NULL OR  @dateFin IS NULL OR @dateDeb IS NULL)
    BEGIN
          RAISERROR('error',16,1);
    END
END;
```

Here is the error that I get:

> Msg 207, Niveau 16, État 1, Procédure tgr_suspTVA, Ligne 13
>   Nom de colonne non valide : 'N_CatCompta'.
>
> Msg 207, Niveau 16, État 1, Procédure tgr_suspTVA, Ligne 13
>   Nom de colonne non valide : 'Exon N°'.
>
> Msg 207, Niveau 16, État 1, Procédure tgr_suspTVA, Ligne 13
>   Nom de colonne non valide : 'Date Fin'.
>
> Msg 207, Niveau 16, État 1, Procédure tgr_suspTVA, Ligne 14
>   Nom de colonne non valide : 'Date début'.

Comment: You have two MAJOR problems here. The select statement for populating your variables doesn't have a FROM clause. The bigger issue is that you are using scalar variables in your trigger. Triggers fire once per operation in sql server not once per row. You need to reference the inserted virtual table and handle your code appropriately. Most likely an exists.

Comment: I don't see a `FROM ` for that `SELECT`

Comment: @SeanLange Your comment covers pretty much the whole question, I think that you should add it as an answer

Comment: actually, if all you want to do is raise an error, you could do that better with a CHECK constraint and not a trigger.

Comment: I think @TabAlleman's answer is the best option. If you are deadset on using a trigger read my previous comment as it is critical to understanding how triggers work.

Answer (score 1):

Triggers are not the best way to constrain your data and raise errors when an insert tries to break your rules.

The best way to do this is with constraints.   Even a complex rule like this can be handled with a simple [CHECK constraint](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.F_COMPTET
ADD CONSTRAINT chkCompta4 CHECK (N_CatCompta<>4 OR 
([Exon N°] IS NOT NULL  
 AND [Date Fin] IS NOT NULL
 AND [Date début] IS NOT NULL
));
```

Add this constraint to your table, and any insert that tries to break this rule will raise a constraint violation error.

A trigger would be useful if, when a row breaks your rule, you wanted to do an insert into a different table.  But as long as you are only dealing with the one table, there is no need for a trigger.

Comment: i tryed your code but i get this error 
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0 , Line 1
The ALTER TABLE statement is in conflict with the CHECK constraint " chkCompta " . The conflict occurred in the " SONELECT " database table " dbo.F_COMPTET " . I used trigger because when N_CatCompta then ([Exon N°] IS NOT NULL  
 AND [Date Fin] IS NOT NULL
 AND [Date début] IS NOT NULL when user tryes to insert

Comment: OK, no.  You only run the Alter Table once.  You don't put it in a trigger.  In fact, you remove the trigger and don't have one at all.

Comment: Well the error indicates you're trying to add a constraint that already exists, so you should be good already.

Comment: ok but i want o show a personalized message when this constrain is brokien

Comment: You would have to do that in your code that does the INSERT.   Catch the constraint error and raise a different error message.

Answer (score 0):

Although I think the check constraint that Tab Alleman posted is a better approach you might be stuck using a trigger.

If that is the case, you have two MAJOR problems here. The select statement for populating your variables doesn't have a FROM clause. The bigger issue is that you are using scalar variables in your trigger. Triggers fire once per operation in sql server not once per row. You need to reference the inserted virtual table and handle your code appropriately. Most likely an exists.

Comment: I edted my trger like this: